# How do I use a separate database every single time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to use different databases (different email id's) in $dbname based on the user login email id. What changes should I make.

I have created various databases with the name of various user email id's who have registered themselves. Here in the above snippet, I am using the test database but lets say if a user is logging in, then I want him to use his database i.e. database by his email id's name. How can I achieve so.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$con = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql1 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `cn` ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"); 
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($sql1);
?>
```

There are no such error messages but the issue is that the changes take place in the tables of the test database, whereas i want the same changes to be done in the user's database and not test database.

Comment: You should add a user table and add the user's ID to the relevant tables.

Comment: Having a separate database for each person is a **really bad idea**. What problem do you think you are trying to solve by using that approach?